# NXP poduct NCF3340AHN

Tags: can-bus

I wanna know about this NCF3340AHN controller. The NXP NCF3340 is ideally suited for easy integration of NFC technology into automotive devices because it provides an NCI interface.
I want to know is there any development boards for this controller?
Is it supports to CAN or do I need to configure it with CAN?
Because I am doing it for automotive devices, but I didn't got any info regarding CAN. Please help to do operation with CAN.

Thanks in advance.